# I need help with a proof in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I could use help with the following problem:

Show that if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are three events such that
$P(A \cap B \cap C) \neq 0$ and $P(C \mid A \cap B)$ = $P(A \mid B)$,
then $P(C) = P(A \mid B)$.

Here is my attempt to solve the problem:

$$P(C \mid A \cap B) = { {P(A \cap B \cap C)} \over {P(A \cap B)}} = P(C \mid B) = {{P(C \cap B)} \over {P(B)}}$$

However, at this point I do not know what to do. Please help.

Note: This is not a homework problem

Bob

Comment: This just seems false. Let $B \subset C = A$ with $P(B)>0$ and $P(C)<1$; then all your conditional probabilities equal $1$ but $P(C)$ does not.

Comment: I am sorry but I got the question wrong. Let me try again. Bob